# Very slow performance of my custom use of std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, std

I am trying to store some information of a graph in an unordered_map. Each edge has some parameters. There are 120 edges, and each edge has 90*2 different parameters.

I have the following implementation of `std::unordered_map<>`

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int> metric_tuple_key; // metric  tuple key


// define a hash function for this metric_tuple_key tuple
struct m_KeyHash : public std::unary_function<metric_tuple_key, std::size_t> {
        std::size_t operator()(const metric_tuple_key& k) const {
            // the magic operation below makes collisions less likely than just the standard XOR
            std::size_t seed = std::hash<int>()(std::get<0>(k));
            seed ^= std::hash<int>()(std::get<1>(k)) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
            seed ^= std::hash<int>()(std::get<2>(k)) + 0x9e3779b97f4a7c15 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
            return seed ^ (std::hash<char>()(std::get<3>(k)) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2));
        }
    };

// define the comparison operator for this  metric_tuple_key tuple
struct m_KeyEqual : public std::binary_function<metric_tuple_key, metric_tuple_key, bool> {
        bool operator()(const metric_tuple_key& v0, const metric_tuple_key& v1) const {
            return (std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) && std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) &&
                    std::get<2>(v0) == std::get<2>(v1) && std::get<3>(v0) == std::get<3>(v1));
        }
    };

std::unordered_map<metric_tuple_key, double, m_KeyHash, m_KeyEqual>           _metrics;
```

I was able to insert the values into `_metrics` by creating a tuple key.

Now, I want to get some values from `_metrics` when a key is specified.

```
//Retrieve around 120  double values. Total number of entries in _metrics is 21600
double k = _metrics.at((std::make_tuple(m, k, edge.first, edge.second))). //do this 120 times
```

This turns out to be very slow (almost 400 ms). I was hoping that it would take around a millisecond or less.

Am I doing anything wrong or is std::unordered_map not suitable for my use case. I had used python dictionaries before to solve this same issue and retrieval of values is near instantaneous in python dicts

edit:
some unordered_map stats:

```
 max_load_factor: 1

 size: 21600

 bucket_count: 25717

 load_factor: 0.839911
```

Edit: Timer Code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Timer {
private:
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start , stop;;

public:

    void startClock();
    void stopClock();
    void elapsedTime(std::string &message);

};
#include "Timer.hpp"

void Timer::startClock() {
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

void Timer::stopClock() {
    stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
}


void Timer::elapsedTime(std::string &message) {
    auto diff = stop - start;
    std::cout << "Elapsed time for " <<message<< " " << std::setprecision(13) <<std::chrono::duration <double, std::milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

and the Time measurement is

```
T_met.startClock();
for (const auto& edges: list_of_arcs())
{
    double k = _metrics.at((std::make_tuple(m, k, edge.first, edge.second)))
}
T_met.stopClock();
```

Comment: Certainly seems reasonable to me,  worth to check you are definitely getting good variance on your hash values so that it's not falling through to a linear search for each lookup. What is the bucket count, load factor?

Comment: I am unfortunately not familiar with those terms. I will look them up and let you know.

Comment: You can get these metrics out of the map using the associated member functions.

Comment: @wobr I added them to the question.

Comment: Why are you using `hash<char>` sometimes for the integer elements in the tuple?

Comment: This was my previous code. I did change it to `int` but the results are not much different.

Comment: How are you measuring time? Profiling code in C++ is highly nuanced. You should explain how and what you’re timing

Comment: Why do you define a custom comparison operator? What is wrong with the one provided by `std::tuple`?

Comment: @alterigel I added the timing code.

Comment: @DanielLangr I am not sure. I was using someone else's code. I will look into it.

Comment: Just want to check you are dividing the elapsed time by the number of lookups (length of list_of_arcs())? (Sorry for asking ;))

Comment: Why are you defining the hash function as a functor?!? It doesn't seem to have any state (which is expected for a hash function), so using a functor seems plain overkill.

Comment: @wobr: No. I am not. I need to sum all the doubles (values for keys). This is the total time for 120 lookups

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica not really sure. I got this code from online and just modified it for my use.

Comment: are you using an optimised build of your program? Performance measurements on debug builds are meaningless especially in the presence of complex templated code

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes. I am compiling with -O3

Comment: @Morpheus We once solved a similar problem and found out, that it was caused by too complex hash function (similar to yours). Then, we switched to a hash function where we simply juxtapose less significant bytes from each tuple element into a single integer and used it as an argument for `std::hash` call. You may want to try it and see what happens (of course, the outcome very much depends on data, but in our case, it worked very well).

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the suggestion. I should probably learn how to do what you have asked me to do as I borrowed this code from someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search duration is depended of quality of your hash.
For test, you can use "map" - it has stable seach duration.
If map is faster than unordered map - your hash is bad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if my hashing function is good or not (I included in the question). If it is bad, how can I improve?

Comment: I dont know the ways to improve your hash function :(   .  But:

Comment: According your statistic: you should check the duration of key's hash calculation. It may be slightly high.

Comment: @Morpheus: You could try to improve your hash function by using [`boost::hash_combine`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) or change your tuple to `std::array<int, 4>` and use `boost::hash` which has a specialization for `std::array`.